# UEFI logo takes hours to appear

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

Acer E1-572P laptop. 4GB memory; 500GB hard disc. Windows 10 Home (upgraded from Windows 8.1 18 months ago).

From switch on the Acer BIOS logo takes hours to appear. Over the last 3-4 weeks the problem ahs got worse. A week ago it was appearing in about 15 minutes it now takes over 6 hours. Once the logo appears its boots normally and runs Windows 10 perfectly. During the delay the disc light flashes every 1-2 secs.

I have run MEMTEST 86 (under DOS) - not faults. 
I have run the Seagate disc test - no faults.
I have rest the UEFI firmware to defaults by shorting out two contacts under the memory (as instructed on an Acer website).
I have changed from UEFI boot to Legacy boot no difference.
None of the devices in Windows device manager show any problems.

Since it takes so long to display the Acer logo it is extremely difficult to get into the UEFI to check/change settings.

The problem has to be in the POST not in Windows. Any assistance will be apreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a different HDD?

Comment: Sometimes this also happens when there are issues with the CMOS battery.

Comment: Disable to show that logo in BIOS. I don't know if there is an option to to that in Acer bios. But I did it in AM bios.

Comment: Ramhound - I have tried a different hard disc.

Comment: Biswapriyo - I don't understand what you mean by 'Disable to show that logo in BIOS'. It is extremely difficult to change any BIOS options since I would need to sit watching the laptoop until the Acer Logo appears which as I said can take several hours anything from 6 to18 hours!

Comment: Ramhound - I have tried a different hard disc. It still took some hours before it eventually displayed the Acer BIOS logo and then complained the disc had no boot records which is what I expected. I belilve the fault is in the very early stages of the BIOS operation.